# conditional formatting with Case more then one selected

Tags: excel, vba, select, case

I have a VBA like below but when i copy more then 1 cell i get a error because of the multiple selection.

Is it possible to make a action that the Case looks at the selected cells one after the other? Or do i have the wrong Statment?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$G$8:$OA$92")) Is Nothing Then

    With Target
     Select Case .Value
      Case Is = "Weekend"
          .Interior.ColorIndex = 48
      Case Is = "VRIJ", "ADV"
          .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
     End Select
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the cells in the intersect.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G8:OA92")) Is Nothing Then
        on error goto meh
        application.enableevents = false
        dim t as range
        for each t in Intersect(Target, Range("G8:OA92"))
            With t
                Select Case lcase(.Value2)
                    Case "weekend"
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 48
                    Case "vrij", "adv"
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    case else
                        .interior.pattern = xlnone
                End Select
            End With
        next t 
    End If 
meh:
    application.enableevents = true
End Sub
```

Comment: is it possible to search only for part of the text?